# Iterate through a foreach loop in PHP and replace a counter placeholder with str_replace

Tags: php, foreach, count, str-replace, placeholder

This is vaguely WordPress related, but it's purely PHP question.

I have a function that gets all the images in a post and the function lets me control what comes before and after the images i.e. `<figure>` and `</figure>`.

I have a function like this:

```
function get_some_images( $args = "" ) {
    $defaults = array(
        'before_img' => '<figure>', 
        'after_img'  => '</figure>', 
        );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );
    // $images is an array of images from the curren post
    $i = 1;
    foreach($images as $image) {
        // Pseudocode
        $output .= $before_img . $image . $after_img;
        $i++;
    }
    return $output; 
}
```

Usage:

```
$args = array(
    'before_img' => '<div class="img">',
    'after_img'  => '</div>',
    );
echo get_some_images($args);
```

All fine so far. But what if I want to add an iteration counter to the `before_img`, I'm using `%d` as a placeholder:

```
$args = array(
    // Here's the difference, note the %d placeholder for iteration count
    'before_img' => '<div class="img-%d">',
    'after_img'  => '</div>',
    );
get_some_images($args);
```

I tried something like this:

```
$i = 1;
foreach($images as $image) {
    // Here's the tricky bit
    $before_img = str_replace('%d', $i, $before_img);
    $output .= $before_img . $image . $after_img;
    $i++;
}
```

But it won't iterate the counter, outputs same number for all the iterations:

```
<div class="img-1"><img></div>
<div class="img-1"><img></div>
<div class="img-1"><img></div>
...
```

If I echo the `$i` out, it's iterated normally:

```
$i = 1;
foreach($images as $image) {
    echo $i . ', ';
    $i++;
}
// Outputs: 1, 2, 3...
```

I tried some nested loops also, but with little luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this for checking purpose :

```
<?php
   function get_some_images( $args = "" ) {
   $images=[1,2,3];
// $images is an array of images from the curren post
    $i = 1;
  foreach($images as $image) {
    $before_img='<div class="img-%d">';
   $after_img='</div>';
    // Here's the tricky bit
    $before_img = str_replace('%d', $i, $before_img);
    $output .= $before_img . $image . $after_img;
   $i++;
   }
    var_dump($output);
    return $output; 
  }

  get_some_images($args);


  ?>
```

and it yields this :
                     `<div class="img-1">1</div>
                      <div class="img-2">2</div>
                      <div class="img-3">3</div>`

you can go to : http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php   and then after excuting this piece of code (with in php tags) ... inspecting the output will show u this div structure .. Hope it helps .. Cheers!

Comment: Alrite, if `$before_img='<div class="img-%d">';` is outside the loop it won't work, interesting. Thanks for the answer.